# How to Un-format a document in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-formatting

So there's a messy XML file where all white spaces between tags have been stripped, so it's a valid XML file but it's somewhat unreadable.

I press the magic `Ctrl+K, D`, and the file is beautifully formatted.

I edit it, and then I want to put it back into the compressed, hardly readable state, removing all whitespaces between the tags. How do I do that in VS 2008? I looked though the list of all available commands but couldn't find any.

Comment: To save space (the file is rather huge, it's got about half a megabyte of whitespaces) and to leave things in the state I found them in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using Notepad++

I recommend you get [Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/files/) and install the [XML Tools plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/). The `Plugins > XML Tools` menu contains a `Linarize XML` item that does exactly what you want.

#### Using Visual Studio

You could do a Find & Replace using a regular expression.

First remove all the whitespace preceding any XML tags using these search criteria:

> Find what: `:Wh*[<]`
> Replace with: `<`

Then remove all the whitespace preceding any text or attributes:

> Find what: `:Wh+{:Al}`
> Replace with:  `\1`

**Note:** There should be a space in front of `\1`.

**Disclaimer:** This method may not be completely accurate, so make sure to double-check the result!

Comment: You beat me to it, +1 for the recommendation of Notepad++... seems like your answer is more complete than the one I was about to post anyway! 8-)

Comment: The regexp will hardly work, given the contents of CDATA sections, but I like your answer most.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to select all the file and then keep pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until you've removed all the tabs. It won't remove all the white space though, just that at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can come back to the original formatting if you made edits. What I would do is use emacs macros: you can do a set of keys for one line and repeat it for the whole file:

C-x (   start recording key strokes to build a keyboard macro.

C-x )   stop recording key strokes to for a keyboard macro.

then the following instruction will repeat it 200 times:

C-u 200 C-x e

(I know Visual Studio and emacs are different worlds but in some situations emacs and cygwin are the only way to go really)

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the table but you can just run two replace-bits.

1. First press Ctrl-H while having the XML open in Visual Stuido. This will bring up replace-window. Make sure you check "Use regular expressions"-box in the replace-window
2. Search term should contain **\r\n** and replace term just empty textbox without spaces. Press **Replace all** This will now remove all the newlines
3. In order to remove all spaces between tags make sure replace term contains **> +<** (there is a space before the plus sign) and replace term **><** Now press **Replace all**

Voila

Comment: Step 2 will remove all new lines in the data (the significant white space). Step 3 will [mess up with CDATA sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164470/how-to-un-format-a-document-in-visual-studio-2008/53866328#comment3255479_3164732).

Comment: so you got pure values on each new line without tags? how about stripping new lines only between tags like searching for >(\r\n)+< ?  And you are not to strip whitespaces between start/closing tags in CDATA?

Comment: There might be a `<text></text>` tag with multiline text in it. These line breaks must be preserved. CDATA sections may contain tags in them that is considered data, they also must be preserved if they contain line breaks, even between what looks like a tag (although they do not count as tags in a CDATA section).